# Multiple Views in Xcode 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm having a lot of trouble finding a tutorial for implementing multiple views in Xcode 4.2 without storyboard, this is for a class so I can't use storyboard yet.  I'm just trying to have a 2nd view with a UIPicker come up when a button is clicked in the main view, I just can't find one for this version of Xcode and it's different enough from the older versions to confuse me.

Any help appreciated if someone can give me a quick description of what I need to do this or a newer tutorial I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. What does the version of Xcode have to do with your question exactly? You can create a UIView subclass by selecting File > New > New File.

Comment: I've been able to do that, but how do I link it to the button on my first view?

Comment: Hey there user1208173. I hope my answer was helpful to you, let me know if you have any other questions. If my answer helped solve your problem, it would be much appreciated if you selected it as the right answer, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think you should read the [UIView Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html) to get a good handle on how `UIView`s work exactly. I find nibs/storyboard are really great at confusing new iOS developers.

In essence, a `UIViewController` has 1 view which you set in the `viewDidLoad` or `loadView` method by using the `[self setView:someUIView]`. You add more stuff to the screen by adding `UIView`s as a subview of the viewcontroller's "Main" view. For example

```
-(void)loadView {
    // Create a view for you view controller
    UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self setView:mainView];

    // Now we have a view taking up the whole screen and we can add stuff to it
    // Let's try a button, a UIButton is a subview of UIView
    UIButton *newButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    // We need to set a frame for any view we add so that we specify where it should
    // be located and how big it should be!
    [newButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
    // Now let's add it to our view controller's view
    [self.view addSubview:newButton];

    // You can do the same with any UIView subclasses you make!
    MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc] init];
    [myView setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];

}
```

Now here we have our viewController who'se view is just a plain UIView which in turn has 2 subviews; newButton and myView. Since we created the MyView class, maybe it contains subviews as well! Let's take a look at what a UIView subclass could look like:

```
// Here is the init method for our UIView subclass
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Let's add a button to our view
        UIButton *newButton2 = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        // Of course, the frame is in reference to this view
        [newButton2 setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
        // We add just using self NOT self.view because here, we are the view!
        [self addSubview:newButton2];

    }
    return self;
}
```

So in this example we would have a view controller who'se view now contains 2 button! But the view structure is a tree:

```
           mainView
          /      \
  newButton     myView
                  \
                newButton2
```

Let me know if you have any other questions!

Matt

Comment: +1 for taking your time, i hope your help won't result in user1208173 not reading PG :)