# Beautiful UI ideas for IOS App

Tags: ios

I wanted to know if someone can point me out on how to accomplish some of the iOS apps have done which makes the app so attractive :

1. NESS iPhones app's glassy looking UITableViewCells. I dissected their app and was able to find out that they use glass images for left, right, top left corners of the cell, but not sure what property of the cell would allow you to use these images.
2. Localmind'a app - When they introduce a new feature they have these floating hints which point to the new buttons in their UI bringing the user's attention to the new button or UI element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating hints would be a `UIView` subclass. You can add subviews in its init method (like `UILabels`, set the background color, etc) or use CoreGraphics to draw manually in the `drawRect:` method (which s alot more efficient). Then you simply add this view to the main view of the view controller you are using. Fancy cells can be done the same way. You can create your own UIView subclass to represent a cell, add/draw whatever you want and add it to a plain UITableViewCell's contentView. Alternatively you can look into subclassing UITableViewCell, but it is not usually necessary.

See this answer for more on [how UIViews work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271159/multiple-views-in-xcode-4-2/9282434#9282434)

See this for [custom UITableViewCell](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)

See the reference material on [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) and [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)